# Exception clickthrough using DDEV and Vscode on Drupal 10 with Ignition

Tags: drupal, ddev

I'm using the Ignition module on Drupal 10.
When I encounter an exception, the link to open the file is invalid; it points to the file inside of the DDEV container, something VSCode can't see.

How can I get serve my website via DDEV, and get the click-through function working with DDEV?

### Test

1. Install Ignition module on Drupal 10.
2. Create a new module, with a route that has a missing controller.

```yaml
bad_module.settings:
  path: '/bad_module'
  defaults:
    _controller: 'Drupal\bad_module\Controller\MissingController'
    _title: 'Bad routing'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'administer modules'
```

3. Access '/bad_module' will throw an `InvalidArgumentException` exception due to missing controller.
4. Click "ClassResolver:24" should open my IDE at the file.

[image]

Drupal: 10.0

Ignition: 1.0@alpha2

OS: WSL2 Ubuntu on Win10

VSCode: 1.74.3

DDEV: 1.21.4, vHEAD-a0f42dd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

There seems to be 2 things we need to fix:

1. Get web container to use our config file.

```bash
# Create a new one
touch ./.ddev/homeadditions/.ignition.json

# Alternatively, use an existing one as the new base
mv ~/.ignition.json ./.ddev/homeadditions
```

2. Configure `.ignition.json` to remap the directories.

```json
    "editor": "vscode-remote",
    "remote_sites_path": "/var/www/html",
    "local_sites_path": "wsl+Ubuntu/home/user13/drupal/ignition-d10-demo"
```

Because I'm using DDEV and VSCode via WSL, I need to following settings:

- `vscode-remote` is VCode using one of the remote extensions
- `remote_sites_path` is the project root inside DDEV
- `local_sites_path` is the path of my project where

  - `wsl` is the remote style (as opposed to `ssh`)
  - `Ubuntu` is the WSL OS (`wsl -l`)
  - `/home/user13/drupal/ignition-d10-demo` is the path inside WSL (`pwd`)

Full `.ddev/homeadditions/.ignition.json`

```json
{
    "theme": "dark",
    "editor": "vscode-remote",
    "hide_solutions": false,
    "remote_sites_path": "/var/www/html",
    "local_sites_path": "wsl+Ubuntu/home/user13/drupal/ignition-d10-demo"
}
```